# Java - Create Process Error = 193

Tags: java

I am trying to run an external program, which is an executable JAR file.  It can be executed by a double-click, but when I use `Runtime.exec()` I get an error that the file is "not a windows32 application".

```
try {       
    String filepath = "C://Users//Name//Desktop//Speedtest.jar";    
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filepath);        
} catch (IOException e) {       
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's not how you run a jar. However, there must be a better way to do this... if this jar contains bytecode, why don't you just add it to your classpath ?

Comment: Re-worded for grammar and clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jar file in itself is not a win-32 application. (It is actually like a zip file.)

`java` is a win-32 application, which runs the jar file.

So, you need to run the jar file using the command:

```
java -jar <jar-file>
```

You can do this:

```
String filepath = "java -jar C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Speedtest.jar";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filepath);
```

This should work fine.

Comment: True, but I'd not recommend it. Calling a jar from a command-line within a Java program is just awkward

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a program inside a jar, just add it to your classpath when you run your main program:

`java -cp /path/to/your.jar package.name.MainClass`

(or simply add to the libraries in your IDE)